# Doctrine2 architecture design - entity with supplemental data

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

first of all I'd like to apologise in advance for the question title as it might not ideally explain the situation I'm dealing with. I've done some research but had no luck finding a suitable solution.

My Case:

I'm having an entity, say an Activity, which represents activities that customers on my website perform. It can be of a different type like: page_view, comment, login, purchase etc. What I'm trying to do is to assign supplemental data to each activity eg. for a comment activity supplemental data would be a comment entity, for purchase an array of product entities etc.
   For now I'm simply defining activity types as constants in ActivityInterface, and then use that values to get an EntityManager instance that is capable of resolving the correct entity/entities from parameters provided in http request. This solution has many downsides and I'm not sure if that's event a right approach.

Could you guys help me out by giving me some hints or redirect me to some useful publications on how to bite that subject? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a [Mapped Superclass](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) like so:

```
/** @MappedSuperclass */
class Activity
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    protected $generalActivityProperty;

    // ... more fields and methods
}

/** @Entity */
class Comment extends Activity
{

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity='CommentEntity') */
    private $commentEntity;

    // ... more fields and methods
}

/** @Entity */
class Purchase extends Activity
{

    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity='ProductAssociations') */
    private $products;

    // ... more fields and methods
}
```

This will create a single table per Class (but not for 'Activity') each containing all fields/methods defined in 'Activity' and the additional fields/methods as defined in the specific classes.

You can even query all activities by the `entityManager->getRepository('Acticity')->find()` e.g. and get a list of Comment, PageView etc. Objects back.

It's not tested, but you should get an idea how to do it.

You could as well use `Single Table Inheritance` or `Class Table Inheritance`. Check it out [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

But I guess in your case a Mapped Superclass should be perfect.